# How can implement a navigationLink inside of a LazyVGrid and ForEach statement?

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-navigationlink, lazyvgrid

How can I implement play buttons that navigate to different views in the corner of each music category item? Here is an image of what I am looking for:

[image: What I am looking for]

Here is my code:

```
struct ScrollCategories: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid (columns: [GridItem(.fixed(200)), GridItem(.fixed(200))]) {
                    ForEach(musics) { sub in
                        ZStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                //Hidden Code
                            } // END OF VSTACK
                            NavigationLink {
                                // Naviagte to a different view!
                                Onboarding()
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "play.circle")
                                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                                    .padding(.leading, -72.0)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 130.0)
                            }
                        } // END OF ZSTACK
                    }// END OF FOR EACH
                } // END OF GRID ITEM
            } // END OF SCROLL VIEW
        } //END OF ZSTACK
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a navigation link, yet it does not show in the preview or simulator.

Here is an image of what the preview looks like:
[image: What the XCode preview looks like]

Comment: This needs a [mre]

Comment: Where's your `NavigationStack` or `NavigationView`? There's none in your example, and unless the navigation links are within one they won't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your navigation link is there. You just use padding too high that it was out of the frame. You can use `ZStack` with `alignment` to put on the left-top corner and add `padding` to make it nice.

```
ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) { <- positioning for each View
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        //Hidden Code
    } // END OF VSTACK// END OF VSTACk

    NavigationLink {
        // Navigate to a different view!
        Onboarding()
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "play.circle")
            .font(.system(size: 30)) 
            .padding( {{ put your desire padding }}) 
    }
} // END OF ZSTACK
```

[image]